# sqlite3 - CONDITION ON INSERT

Tags: sqlite

I have a database which contain the name and properties of two different classes of files which are filled after the server send it to a client. So what I would like to do is something like that:

```
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT Count() FROM files_table_1 WHERE id="some id") IS NOT 0
        THEN (UPDATE files_table_1 SET(...) WHERE id="some id")
    ELSE (INSERT INTO files_table_2 (...) VALUES(...))
    END;
```

But does not work.

Is there some way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Well, I'm working with Qt, so cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @CL. comment, it's seems there is no way to run this command on one unique sqlite stament, so I will go like this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN (SELECT Count() FROM files_table_1 WHERE id="some id") IS 1 THEN 1
    WHEN (SELECT Count() FROM files_table_2 WHERE id="some id") IS 1 THEN 2
    ELSE -1 END;
query.next();

if(query.value(0).toInt() == 1)
{
    query.prepare("UPDATE file_table_1 SET ...");
    ...
}
else if(query.value(0).toInt() == 2)
{
    query.prepare("UPDATE file_table_2 SET ...");
    ...
}
else if(query.value(0).toInt() == -1)
{
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO file_table_2 ...");
    ...
}
```

I don't mark this option as correct because I think there should be a "more sophisticated way to do that.
If anyone as any suggestion, it's welcome.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

C++ has the keyword `if` for situations like this:

```cpp
bool ok = query.exec("UPDATE ...");
...
if (query.numRowsAffected() == 0) {
    ok = query.exec("INSERT ...");
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm looking for doing it directly from sqlite command in order to re-run query.exec.

Comment: This is not possible with a single SQL statement. However, C++ also has functions.

Comment: Thanks again! I have add another way to do the same you suggest.